# Display bug in protected cell

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm using Sencha ExtJS 5, and I'm experiencing a display blug, as you can see below :

[image]

This cell is protected, and this bug appears when I do as follow :

- I click on a protected cell on time : the text move a little bit to the left
- I click on an other protected cell : the bug appears

When I click elsewhere on an unprotected cell, the bug disappears.

Do you guys know if this is a known bug in ExtJS ?

Comment: How did you "protect" cells in ExtJS?

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)?